# How to access thread variables?

Tags: java, multithreading

How to access the thread variable from outside of the thread , I have the hashmap inside the thread which I want to access from my main program or service.

```
public class Sample {

class Thread {

//private synchronized hashmap declared here
}

}
```

I want to access the hashmap declared in Thread in other class lets say Class Abc

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is difficult to say much more than: alsmot the same way you would access a variable in a class from another class. It would require some synchronization to be thread safe.

Comment: What is "inside the thread "? Inside the base thread class (extended from Thread or implementing Runnable), or inside the local variables of the methods executing on the thread?

Comment: @assylias if you posted that as an answer I would +1 it too, fwiw

Comment: Only local variables are "in a thread" as they are on the stack.  Objects are on the heap and can be shared between threads.

Comment: Are you talking about ThreadLocal?

Comment: @assylias : Look answer from Tobiaz its similar in line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem with multiple threads accessing data is synchronization. If you have a map with data, make it a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), and place it so that you can access it. Now you have access to the data in your map. Note that there could be other dependencies in your code that require more synchronization, but at least accessing the data in the map is safe.

**Update**: In your case I would do something like:

```
public class Sample {
    Map mMyMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    void foo() {
        // Access from here
    }

    class Thread {
        // And from here
    }
}
```

You can make it private, but there is much to say about inner classes and private that is out of scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks. I have the concurrent hash map.But how to access this map outside of thread from my main program is my concern now.

Comment: Do you mean from other classes/objects? Your thread class is like any other class. It shares the heap just as they say in the comments above. You can use getter and setter methods, fields, etc. If you post some code it is easier to help you.

Comment: Okay...I am updating my query